# Unify the roles and caps?

Tags: capabilities, user-roles

I installed several plugins(buddypress-docs,achievement,bbpress), each one create capabilities for their own post_type.
I would prefer to make all roles and capabilities unified into one system, Is there a solution to overwrite all existing caps and control all post_types? Eventually I would like to organize users by group, and assign each user group different caps across all types.

Comment: Some examples would be very helpful. [Be specific!](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) :)

Comment: just added the plugin names

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Members Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/). This will allow you to create a new roles (which you can then assign to the groups) with their own cap or mixture thereof.

Comment: for example, in the CPT templates, it normally has conditional tags such as if(bp_docs_user_can($cap)), then, display the content. So, after I use Members or Role-scope, how the CPT templates cope up ?

Comment: http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/07/10/meta-capabilities-for-custom-post-types and http://justintadlock.com/archives/2012/10/16/how-i-run-a-membership-site should point you in the right direction.

Comment: just finished reading the 2 articles,great resource! I tried Members before, it seems to me it doesn't handle the situation where I want to allow certain users to have the cap to edit posts under a category.

Answer (score 0):

Members plugin will do exactly what you're looking for. I use it in conjuntion with manually adding caps:

```
// Manipulating a role's capabilities -> http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#edit_posts
function manipulate_role(){
   $role = get_role( 'Master Editor' ); // pick up role to edit

   $role->add_cap( 'edit_users' );
   $role->remove_cap( 'update_core' );         
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'manipulate_role');
```

Maybe it's just me but I found that [mapping your own cpt's](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/88307/custom-post-types-capabilities-map-meta-cap-issues/88397#88397) is the worst idea ever...

Download Map Cap for that instead of coding your "maps". WP has a ways to go with roles and caps and you'll never be able to write code that works as good or better than what Map Cap can accomplish with a few checkboxes.