# Custom Post Type's Capabilities map_meta_cap issues

Tags: user-roles

I've created a CPT, added capabilities to it and them to the Subscriber role successfully.

However the mapping is clearly not working because I get errors on publish and a Subscriber cannot edit their own posts (which the function below allows if they are the author). Why won't my map_meta_cap function work?

I've spent all weekend on this so I have to turn to the community. Thanks in advance.

```
function lst_map_meta_cap( $caps, $cap, $user_id, $args ) {

/* If editing, deleting, or reading an event, get the post and post type object. */
if ( 'edit_lstpost' == $cap || 'delete_lstpost' == $cap || 'read_lstpost' == $cap ) {
$post = get_post( $args[0] );
$post_type = get_post_type_object( $post->post_type );
$caps = array();

switch( $cap ) {
case 'edit_lstpost':
$caps[] = ( $user_id == $post->post_author ) ? $post_type->cap->edit_posts : $post_type->cap->edit_others_posts;
break;
case 'delete_lstpost':
$caps[] = ( $user_id == $post->post_author ) ? $post_type->cap->delete_posts : $post_type->cap->delete_others_posts;
break;
case 'read_lstpost':
$caps[] = ( 'private' != $post->post_status || $user_id == $post->post_author ) ? $caps[] = 'read' : $post_type->cap->read_private_posts;
break;
 }
}

return $caps;
}

add_filter( 'map_meta_cap', 'lst_map_meta_cap', 10, 4 );
```

EDIT:
Also adding all caps to the administrator refuses to work the way I understand it to after reading for 2 days about it. I have played with applying/removing each of the caps to the admin/subscriber role with only the ability to view or create (with an error but still works)

Here are the CPT caps:

```
[edit_post] => edit_lstpost
[read_post] => read_lst
[delete_post] => delete_lstpost
[edit_posts] => edit_lstposts
[edit_others_posts] => edit_lstothers
[publish_posts] => publish_lst
[read_private_posts] => read_privatelst
[delete_posts] => delete_lstposts
[delete_private_posts] => delete_private_lstcapss
[delete_published_posts] => delete_published_lstcapss
[delete_others_posts] => delete_lstothers
[edit_private_posts] => edit_private_lstcapss
[edit_published_posts] => edit_published_lstcapss
[edit_page] => edit_lstpage
[create_posts] => edit_lstposts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it's a real bad idea to map your own meta capabilities. To solve this problem I ended up going through the steps you would with a map_meta_cap function with TWO plugins.

Use [[Map Cap]](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/map-cap/) to automatically map the meta capabilities of my new custom post type to my specific user roles.

Then had to install the Very useful [Members Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/) which I manually had to assign the capabilities with add_cap and double check within the plugin for proper cap assigning.

```
function role_set (){
global $wp_roles;

$role = get_role( 'administrator' );
$role->add_cap( 'publish_POST_TYPE' );
$role->add_cap( 'edit_POST_TYPE' );
$role->add_cap( 'edit_others_POST_TYPE' );
$role->add_cap( 'delete_others_POST_TYPE' );
$role->add_cap( 'read_private_POST_TYPE' );
$role->add_cap( 'manage_POST_TYPE' );

}
add_action('init', 'role_set');
```

Then double checked it within the members plugin. It took 4 days to get my custom post type capabilities working right with all roles. I do believe WordPress is LONG overdue for some core built roles and caps control. Hope this helps anyone out there.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone also struggling with this issue, there is an awesome tutorial that clearly explains how to do it without relying on plugins: https://3.7designs.co/blog/2014/08/restricting-access-to-custom-post-types-using-roles-in-wordpress/

If you need to create a new role, you must do it on your activation hook using the add_role function.

After that, make sure you have these arguments in your post type registration:

```
'capability_type'     => array('POST_TYPE','POST_TYPES'),
'map_meta_cap'        => true,
```

The last step involves adding the rights to each role in the `admin_init` hook:

```
 // Add the roles you'd like to administer the custom post types
 $roles = array('NEW_ROLE','editor','administrator');

 // Loop through each role and assign capabilities
 foreach($roles as $the_role) { 

     $role = get_role($the_role);
     $role->add_cap( 'read_POST_TYPE');
     $role->add_cap( 'read_private_POST_TYPES' );
     $role->add_cap( 'edit_POST_TYPE' );
     $role->add_cap( 'edit_POST_TYPES' );
     $role->add_cap( 'edit_others_POST_TYPES' );
     $role->add_cap( 'edit_published_POST_TYPES' );
     $role->add_cap( 'publish_POST_TYPES' );
     $role->add_cap( 'delete_others_POST_TYPES' );
     $role->add_cap( 'delete_private_POST_TYPES' );
     $role->add_cap( 'delete_published_POST_TYPES' );

 }
```